# Right way to translate collection with A2lix

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, translation, a2lix-translation

I have 2 entities **Category** and **Criteria**, the relation between category and criteria is an OneToMany (bidirectional relation). Without translation I don't have any problems for manage the form (CategoryType and CriteriaType), etc.

Category and Criteria contains a "libelle" attribute and I would like translate those attributes in English and in another language, so I have something like:

```
// Category entity :
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=255)
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
private $libelle; // can't be blank
// other attributes 
// --------

// Criteria entity :
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=255)
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
private $libelle; // can't be blank
```

But here, I use GedmoTranslationBundle and A2lix.

Here is my code:

```
$builder
        ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
                    'translatable_class' => 'Immo\AnnonceBundle\Entity\Category',
                    'locales' => array('fr', 'en'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'fields' => array(

                        'libelle' => array(
                            'field_type' => 'text',
                            'locale_options' => array(
                                'en' => array(
                                    'label' => 'Libellé du critère (en) :',
                                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Example : Convenience, proximity, etc.')
                                ),
                                'fr' => array(
                                    'label' => 'Libellé du critère (fr) :',
                                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Exemple : A proximité, commodités, etc.')
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        'criterias' => array(
                            'field_type' => 'collection',
                            'label' => ' ',
                            'type' => new CriteriaType(),
                            'allow_add' => true,
                            'allow_delete' => true
                        )
                    )

                )
             )
```

CriteriaType :

```
$builder->add('libelle', 'text', array('libelle' => 'Libellé :'))
```

My example above, don't work and I don't have any error message it seems $form->isValid() return false and I don't know why.

I don't know how to manage this correctly, can you shed some light on this? Thanks

EDIT :
The first error came of missing token, now the $form->isValid() is true and I have this error.

But because of 'translatable_class' => 'Immo\AnnonceBundle\Entity\Category', even the libelle of Critera is an object of Category. Any idea to handle that ? Thanks

Comment: What error do you get ? I can't find one in your question.

Comment: In fact, I don't really know how to manage the translation with collection and A2lix. When I submit the form with this code, the result of is not correct, he don't handler correctly the submit data. It's little confuse in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create respective CategoryTranslation and CriteriaTranslation entities for your current Category and Criteria entities. And next:

CategoryType:

```
$builder
    ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
                'translatable_class' => 'Immo\AnnonceBundle\Entity\Category',
                'locales' => array('fr', 'en'),
                'required' => false,
                'fields' => array(
                    'libelle' => array(
                        'field_type' => 'text',
                        'locale_options' => array(
                            'en' => array(
                                'label' => 'Libellé de la categorie (en) :',
                                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Example : Convenience, proximity, etc.')
                            ),
                            'fr' => array(
                                'label' => 'Libellé de la categorie (fr) :',
                                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Exemple : A proximité, commodités, etc.')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )

            )
         )
        ->add('criteria', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CriteriaType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ))
```

CriteriaType:

```
$builder
    ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
                'translatable_class' => 'Immo\AnnonceBundle\Entity\Criteria',
                'locales' => array('fr', 'en'),
                'required' => false,
                'fields' => array(
                    'libelle' => array(
                        'field_type' => 'text',
                        'locale_options' => array(
                            'en' => array(
                                'label' => 'Libellé du critère (en) :',
                                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Example : Convenience, proximity, etc.')
                            ),
                            'fr' => array(
                                'label' => 'Libellé du critère (fr) :',
                                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Exemple : A proximité, commodités, etc.')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
         )
```

Comment: Thanks again, it's finally it's what I did. :) And to avoid duplicate bar of A2lix I did a specific handle.